# SyntaxError when NPM script is executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, npm-scripts

I'm trying to update the dependencies of a React app. This app includes a script defined in `package.json` which generates a message bundle for each locale.

```
"scripts": {
  "build:langs": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node scripts/mergeMessages.js"
}
```

The details of the script are unimportant, but it's very similar to [this one](https://github.com/austintackaberry/i18n-example/blob/master/scripts/mergeMessages.js), which is described in a [react-intl tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/setting-up-internationalization-in-react-from-start-to-finish-6cb94a7af725).

Before upgrading the dependencies, the script worked, but now when I execute `npm run build:langs` on the command-line, I get this error:

```
/applications/my-app/scripts/mergeMessages.js:1
import _objectSpread from "/applications/my-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectSpread";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Module._compile (/applications/my-app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/applications/my-app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/applications/my-app/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js:234:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
```

I guess the babel dependencies are the most relevant. Before the upgrade these were:

```
"babel-core": "6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-loader": "7.1.2",
"babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.4.0",
"babel-preset-react-app": "3.1.2",
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
```

Following the upgrade, the babel dependencies are:

```
"@babel/core": "7.4.4",
"@babel/polyfill": "7.4.4",
"@babel/register": "7.4.4",
"babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
"babel-loader": "8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^8.0.0",
"babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.4.0",
"@babel/cli": "~7.4.4",
"@babel/node": "7.2.2",
```

### Update

I don't have either a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` config file, just the following in `package.json`

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're using a preset for `create-react-app` but you're not running it in `create-react-app `. It's only designed for that specific usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using babel-7, you need to have the following:

Try using `@babel/preset-react` instead of `babel-preset-react-app`.

```
"@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
```

and babel-config in package.json should be:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I tried making the changes you suggested, but now I get "Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'" in my script on the line 

`const babel = require("babel-core");`

Comment: It should be `const babel = require("@babel/core");`

Answer (score 1):

From the [Babel 7 migration guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration):

> The `babel-node` command in Babel 6 was part of the `babel-cli` package. In Babel 7, this command has been split out into its own `@babel/node` package, so if you are using that command, you'll want to add this new dependency.

Comment: I added `@babel/node` just before you posted your answer, but now I get a different error. I've updated my question with the details.

Comment: @Dónal: It seems like Babel is not compiling the `import` syntax into `require` calls  (bear in mind that Node does not natively support ES modules yet). Could you please provide the contents of your `.babelrc`/`babel.config.js` file?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've updated my question with the info you requested.